# Event driven programming across Python and Java

Tags: java, python

I want to write specific components of my application in different languages mainly Java and Python. Certain questions arise from this decision:

1. How can I establish a fast, reliable, and relatively simple method of communication between Java and Python?
2. Using this method of communication, what would be a good way to implement event driven design?

Basically, what I want the app to do is this:

1. Python gets user input and emits a signal every time it receives it.
2. Java listens for input signals from Python and processes the input received from Python
3. Java emits signal with corresponding output for the specific input
4. Python listens for the output signal and displays the output

This is meant to be a "real time" app so performance is a priority.

Comment: 0MQ maybe? http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

Comment: @flup Interesting, I'll take a closer look at it

Comment: For the use case you describe, you can avoid most of the headaches by using Jython. Of course this has its own drawbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good solution called Vert.x : http://vertx.io/

It supports everything you've described. You can write your code in Java, Python, Javascript, Ruby, Groovy and maybe more in the future. It is very good for event driven design.

Comment: very cool stuff, will accept as answer and detail my experience later on. Thanks